# Trigger Alarm When Receive Notification From Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

in my app, I will have an external service that will send messages to firebase, which will send a notification to all devices in a specific topic. So far I can receive the notification, but I need to ring an Alarm when it happens.

The problem is: I receive the notification but can't start the alarm.

So far this is my code for the receiver:

```
    public class MessageReceiver extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, pintent);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pintent);

    }
}
```

And manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MessageReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you got any solution to trigger an alarm after receiving firebase notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't indicate what the problem is.  I assume it is that `MainActivity` is not starting.  That is likely caused by this statement:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

Because you want to start an Activity, not a Service, it should be:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: Edited! Thanks, but this alone would trigger the alarm?

Comment: @Myrium: This correction is needed for your call to `AlarmManager`.  Is `MainActivity` not being started?  Your call to `alarm.setRepeating(...)` doesn't seem necessary or correct.  Why a repeating alarm with 0 interval?

Comment: Looks like i set the parameters wrong, I need only to trigger the alarm once, and open the app into MainActivity